# the match filter must be an expression in an object with mongo aggregation in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

So first here's what I'm trying to do :

I got a datatable with some custom inputs. Users can select skills (php, mysql etc) and the standard text input. Users can select multiple skills. When multiple skills are selected it's supposed to be kind of an AND AND query. So both skills must be available.

The standard text input in datatables would contain information such as the name of a customer, their email or job function.

For example I check PHP and Javascript, in my text search I put Google.
Which would mean I'm looking for a document which has both PHP and Javascript in the tags (Or any of their aliases eg: Javascript => js), and has google in any other field thats listed (Customer, function, sender name, sender email or subject).

But it should also be able to search for documents just matching the skills or only for the text input.

I have been trying to build arrays with all query options and merge those depending on input to the function but so far nothing has been working.

> the match filter must be an expression in an object

So below is an example of a document I got in Mongo

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "superfancyID"
    },
    "parsed": {
        "tags": [
            "sql",
            "php"
        ],
        "customer": "CustomerName",
        "function": "functionName",
        "mail_properties": {
            "senderName": "SenderName",
            "senderEmail": "example@example.com",
            "subject": "FW: Test email",
        }
    }
}
```

Here is some code I got to try and build my query

```
    public function handler(int $skip, int $limit, array $filters, string $filterString = '') {

     # $filters are skills
     # $filterString is a string of everything else you put in the search field of the datatable

     /** @var \MongoDB\Collection $collection */
    $collection = $this->emailRepository->getCollection();

     /** @var array $regex */
    $regex = [];

    if(!empty($filterString))
    {
        $strings = explode(' ', $filterString);

        foreach($strings as $item)
        {
            $regex[] = new Regex($item, 'i');
        }
    }

     #This function basically does the same as above.
     #The only change is that this also goes over any aliases for skills. (Javascript => js)
     /** @var array $aliasRegex */
    $aliasRegex = $this->createAliasRegex($filters);

    $skillsFilters = [];
    #This is where I attempt to create a part of the query for just the skills.
    if(!empty($aliasRegex)) {
        $skillsFilters = [
            '$and' => [
                '$or' => [
                    ['parsed.tags' => [
                        '$in' => $aliasRegex
                    ]]
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }

    $stringFilters = [];
    #This is where I try and build the rest of the query.
    if(!empty($regex)) {
        $stringFilters = ['$or' =>
            ['parsed.function' => [
                '$in' => $regex
            ]],
            ['parsed.mail_properties.subject' => [
                '$in' => $regex
            ]],
            ['parsed.customer' => [
                '$in' => $regex
            ]]
        ];
    }

    $documents = $collection->aggregate([
        [
            '$match' => [
                array_merge($stringFilters, $aliasFilters)
            ]
        ]
        ,[
            '$limit' => $limit,
        ],[
            '$skip' => $skip
        ]
    ]);
```

This is basically all I got, I tried checking my arrays and moving around some parts but nothing has been working for me. I always been getting back the error

> the match filter must be an expression in an object

Comment: did you found the solution?